# Removing header and footer in Elementor

Tags: wordpress, header, themes, footer, elementor

I want to start designing with a blank page in Elementor but can't manage to remove the header and footer defined by the Wordpress theme.
As you can see in the screenshot I have already chosen the option "Elementor canvas." Nevertheless, the page still displays sidebar, header and footer from another theme.

Thanks in advance for any help!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Make a new empty header & footer template and set it to display entire site.

User the theme "Hello Elementor" for a blank page.

Answer (score 0):

The sidebar, header and footer come from you template.

Elementor does not replace them unless you use Elementors theme builder feature to overwrite them.

You can delete them in your theme or use a theme that is intended to have no header and footer.

If you delete it in your theme, make sure to not delete eg. wp_header() and wp_footer() which are important to enqueue styles and other things and not just for display.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! Unfortunately I did not find an option for deleting these elements in the theme (using Ocean WP). Would I need to create for instance a header in theme builder and that would replace the themes header? In that case how would I get rid of the sidebar, as theme builder does not seem to have a sidebar option.

Comment: Deleting header and footer in the theme would mean to edit the files - there is most likely no option in your theme for that. 
This would mean creating a child theme (optional step, but highly recommanded) and there overwrite header.php and footer.php with nearly empty outputs. But sounds like you should rather not go that route.

Comment: Yes - you should be able to create header and footer with Elementor theme builder and you are able to tell elementor to overwrite that part for every page or just for certain pages. 

Maybe you can disable the sidebar in Ocean WP all together. I am not familar with Ocean WP but imagine it is quite flexible.

Comment: Try creating a header and footer in elementor so that the canvas option works fine

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

go to your theme header.php and footer.php

```
locate at wp-content/themes/yourtheme/header.php
and wp-content/themes/yourtheme/footer.php
```

and remove any code you don't need HTML

Comment: I decided to not get rid of them but adapt through the theme builder, but thanks!